# java-Doubly Linked List logic

Tags: java, object, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to understand a java implementation for doubly linked list. I have the following code:

```
public class DLLNode{
    //define variables
    public int info;
    public DLLNode next;
    public DLLNode prev;


    //Passing constructors
    public DLLNode(int i){
        info = i;
        next = prev = null;
    }

    public DLLNode(int i, DLLNode n, DLLNode p){
        info = i;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
    }
}
```

And the following:

```
public class DLL {
    DLLNode head;
    DLLNode tail;

    public DLL(){
        head = tail = null;
    }

    //Check whether list is empty or not
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head == null;
    }

//Insert element to head
    public void insertHead(int n){
        if(isEmpty()){
            head = tail = new DLLNode(n);
        }
        else{
            head = new DLLNode(n, null, head);
            head.next.prev = head;
        }
    }
```

Only the insertHead() method is show here for clarity.

Now I understand that if someone runs insertHead(10) in the main method, if the list is empty; a new object forms and both head and tail reference variables points to that object.

What I don't understand is if list is NOT empty; the code piece is very confusing.

```
head = new DLLNode(n, null, head);
head.next.prev = head; //really confusing, what does this mean??
```

1)What I understand is n=10, null and head are passed to constructor: public DLLNode(int i, DLLNode n, DLLNode p).Then the assignment info=10, next=null and prev=head occurs. One problem is that, if at least one item is available on the list, and I add another item to HEAD position, shouldn't "next" point to the previous head, while "prev" point to null?? Faulty code perhaps??

2)What does the code

```
head.next.prev = head;
```

mean?? And why is it necessary?? I really don't get that logic...:(

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: It seems that you are right, and that it should have been `new DLLNode(n, head, null)` instead. Did you try to run it?

Comment: It compiles for sure, but the logic was confusing with the method name used. That/s what worried me, I was afraid I was missing something trivial.

Comment: Compiles, yes. Runs - not for more than one element. This kind of thing is a good place for experimentation. Play around with it in a debugger and you'll be more confident about whether or not it's good code.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @maraca - because you pass `null` in the *second* parameter and the head in the *third* parameter. The second parameter goes to the `next` - so `next` becomes `null`, and the third parameter goes to the `prev`, which will become the old head. Since `next` is null, `head.next.prev` will throw an NPE.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes I saw the error, the implementation is still correct, just the constructor has it in wrong order. Ok this is basically the same as you say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This implementation is wrong. The `insertHead` would throw a `NullPointerException` if called more than once:

```
 head = new DLLNode(n, null, head);
 head.next.prev = head;  // head.next is null because of the above call
```

Instead, the implementation of the insert should be:

```
public void insertHead(int n) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = new DLLNode(n);
    } else {
        head = new DLLNode(n, head, null);
        head.next.prev = head;
    }
}
```

Inserting the node at head is a two-step action:

1. Create the node, set its **next** pointer to point to the current head and assign it to be the new head of the list.
2. Set the **previous** pointer of the old head to the new head. That's what the statement `head.next.prev = head` does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, but the code is exactly doing what you say (just one mistake), maybe if we use brackets it becomes clearer:

```
(head.next).prev = head;
```

We assign the node we just created to the next node. Or in other words: we update the prev reference of the old head to the new head which is necessairy because

```
head = new DLLNode(n, null, head);
```

creates a new head where previous points to `null` and next is the old head, but the reference of previous of the old head is still `null`.

You have the elements in the constructor in the wrong order (or in the call for creating the new head).

```
public DLLNode(int i, DLLNode p, DLLNode n) {
```

And it works.